java.lang.UnsupporteOperationException:Not supporte yet
Necesito ayudo me sale el problema java.lang.UnsupporteOperationException:Not supporte yet,eso ocurre cuado le dor a create method prepareStatement(java.lang.String) in ClaseSQL.Conexion,y si no le doy click la parte de prepareStatement se pone en rojo como se puede ve en la imagen,cuando trado de realizar un insert a una bd por medio de java,el programa que ocupo para java es el neatbeans21,les dejo el codijo de la conexion y en una imagenes el del probrema:
package ClaseSQL;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Conexion {

    String bd = "accesos";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";

    Connection cx;

    public Conexion() {
    }

    public Connection connectar() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            cx = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bd, user, password);
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conecto con BD " + bd);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error a Conectar con BD " + bd);
        }
        return cx;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Conexion conectar = new Conexion();
        conectar.connectar();
    }

}




Hola Emiliano, bienvenido, la pregunta/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos (todo el código como texto),

cx es un objeto de tu clase Conexion y no veo que tu clase tenga en ningún lado definido el método prepareStatement. Obviamente no puedes usar un método que no existe.

Si revisas tu clase Registro podrás ver que cx es una instancia de tu clase Conexion, pero ella no extiende de Connection, que es la clase con la que puedes crear PrepareStatement.
Tal y como lo tienes diseñado, necesitas invocar al método connectar() que es el que te devuelve una instancia de Connection. Por cierto, el return en ese método debería ir dentro del bloque try.
Intenta lo siguiente:
Conexion
package ClaseSQL;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Conexion 
{
    String bd = "accesos";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";

    Connection cx;

    public Conexion() 
    {
    }

    public Connection connectar() 
    {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            cx = DriverManager.getConnection(url + bd, user, password);
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conecto con BD " + bd);
            return cx;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error a Conectar con BD " + bd);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Conexion conectar = new Conexion();
        conectar.connectar();
    }
}

Registro
public class Registro extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    Connection cx;
    public Registro () 
    {
        Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
        /*
           Lo que te devuelve una instancia de Connection
           es la llamada a connectar de la clase Conexion
           La casi igualdad de términos crea una confusión enorme
           Conviene que crees una clase Conexion
           que extienda de Connection, y usar esa clase en todo
           Es lo que se conoce como clase "envoltorio" (wrapper en inglés)
         */
        cx = conexion.connectar();
        //Resto del código
    }
}

Te recomendaría que para sacarle verdadera utilidad a tu clase Conexion la concibas como un envoltorio de Connection. Precisamente el problema viene porque Conexion no extiende de Connection, y eso hace que no puedas usar sobre ella los métodos como prepareStatement.
Finalmente, advertir que Class.forName es obsoleto desde JDBC 4, basta con usar DriverManager.getConnection. Para más detalles, revisa la documentación:


En versiones anteriores de JDBC, para obtener una conexión, primero había que inicializar el controlador JDBC llamando al método
Class.forName. Este método requería un objeto de tipo
java.sql.Driver. Cada controlador JDBC contiene una o más clases que
implementan la interfaz java.sql.Driver...

Todos los controladores JDBC 4.0 que se encuentran en su ruta de clase se cargan automáticamente. (Sin embargo, debe cargar manualmente
cualquier controlador anterior a JDBC 4.0 con el método
Class.forName).




In previous versions of JDBC, to obtain a connection, you first had to initialize your JDBC driver by calling the method Class.forName.
This methods required an object of type java.sql.Driver. Each JDBC
driver contains one or more classes that implements the interface
java.sql.Driver...

Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class path are automatically loaded. (However, you must manually load any drivers
prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method Class.forName.)



